# overloading assignment operator and header file in c++

Tags: c++, header, overloading, variable-assignment

i want to add a overloaded assignment operator to my object class in c++ but when I do this

```
Cabinet& Cabinet::operator=( const Cabinet& right ) {
    if(&right != this){

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                this->chemicals[i][j] = right.chemicals[i][j];
            }
            
        }
    }
    return *this;
    
}
```

and with a header file like this

```
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Chemical.h"

class Cabinet{
private:
    int rows;
    int id_cabinet;
    int columns;
    Chemical*** chemicals;
    string alphabet [9];
public:   
    Cabinet(int id = 0, int rows = 0, int columns = 0);
    ~Cabinet();
    int getRow();
    int getColumn();
    int plusCount();

};
```

when compiling I get a compile error that says:

```
Cabinet.cpp:146:19: error: definition of implicitly declared copy assignment operator
```

Comment: You have to declare `Cabinet::operator=` in your definition of the class in your header file if you intend to define it later on. Also `Chemical***`? Really?

Comment: First, don't tag this as `C`, since this is C++.  Second, you need a copy constructor to go along with the assignment operator.  I suggest you write the copy constructor first.  Once you do that, the assignment operator becomes a very simple 5 lines of `std::swap` calls.

Comment: `Cabinet& operator=( const Cabinet& right );` -- This is missing from your class.  Almost want to close this as a typo.  Also, that assignment operator, even if you got this to compile without errors, is highly flawed.  So you will jumping out the frying pan and into the fire.

Comment: @NathanPierson i am using 2D arrays with objects inside them .( therefore I needed to use them

Comment: Rethink whatever process led you to `Chemical*** chemicals;`. If it isn't outright wrong, it's... interesting. And interesting processes lead to interesting code and interesting bugs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What do you mean by highly flawed ? I am open to suggestions (btw there are more functions but stack overflow wouldn't let me). I am using 2D arrays to contain chemicals inside a table.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use containers like `std::vector`, I would expect an array of arrays of `Chemical` objects to decay to `Chemical**`. I suppose if `Chemical` itself is the base class for some polymorphic type you'd end up with a `Chemical***`?

Comment: C++ doesn't doesn't do 2D dynamic arrays very well. Consider making a 1D array and wrapping it up in a class so that it LOOKS like it's 2D. [Something like this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op). Note languages that do 2D dynamic arrays well do pretty much what the link describes, but they hide it from you.

Comment: @NathanPierson yes that is the case and it is getting bigger too fast. I am not allowed to use vectors unfortunately but chemical class has too many variables and I have no assignment operator for that I just delete the existing one and create new one that's why it is Chemical*** so I can delete existing one.

Comment: @user4581301 whah thank you it didn't come to my mind might use it .)

Comment: Because no one outright said it, any time you get past two levels of indirection, you're probably [headed in the wrong direction](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). Usually it's a sign that you're making an object or function that's responsible for too much and you'll want some sort of intervening data structure like the matrix class I pointed you at. It encapsulates the storage responsibilities so the rest of your code doesn't have to. Try and keep things stupid, and build stupid things into solutions to complex problems.

Comment: @AlpE -- How do you allocate memory for `Chemical***`?  If you used `new[]` or some other allocation function, where do you deallocate the memory in the current object?  Your code is flawed in that it has a big memory leak.  What `operator=` is supposed to do in that case is in theory, `this` removes all remnants of itself and recreates a copy of what is being passed in.  The difference between that and the copy constructor is that in `operator=`, the object already exists and you have to remove the allocated memory it currently has, but the end-goal is the same

Comment: @AlpE -- The other flaw is that you make no guarantee that `rows` and `columns` in the existing object have the same values as `rows` and `columns` in the object being passed in.  Thus not only would you have a memory leak, you may have a buffer-overrun if the `rows` and `columns` for the passed-in object are greater than the current object.

Comment: *I am not allowed to use vectors unfortunately* -- So the goal of your assignment is not to create and maintain `Cabinet` objects, it is to get into the weeds of maintaining 3D arrays using `new[]`?  I really don't understand these restrictions of not using vector -- the code isn't going to magically write itself because you use vector -- you still have to write the code to maintain `Cabinet` objects.  This is why new programmers drop C++ and go to Java, Python, C#, or other language -- dumb restrictions like not being able to use vector in a program that is not about vectors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yea... sadly because of our curriculum we are restricted to use what we learned in class. But if you wanted to see the code here is the GitHub link .) I think it turned out okay but managing the memory was a hoop .D https://github.com/AlphanEker/Lab-Organizer-cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the function in your header file so you can define it later on.

```
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Chemical.h"

class Cabinet{
private:
    int rows;
    int id_cabinet;
    int columns;
    Chemical*** chemicals;
    string alphabet [9];
public:   
    Cabinet(int id = 0, int rows = 0, int columns = 0);
    Cabinet& operator=( const Cabinet& right );
    ~Cabinet();
    int getRow();
    int getColumn();
    int plusCount();

};
```